# Combining multiple queries into one output array for JSON encode. Best approach?

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

Ok, I've tried this so far by using UNION ALL and compressing it into one query, but my array keys weren't working quite right.

At first I tried this:

```
    $query = "SELECT student_no AS test
            FROM student
            WHERE student_no='$studentno' AND password='$password'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT group_id AS group_id
            FROM student_group
            WHERE student_no='$studentno'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT leader AS leader
            FROM team
            WHERE leader='$studentno'";
```

But it was returning student_no:student_no, student_no:group_id and student_no:leader.

It populates all the keys as student_no, the first query. Or as above, test as I tried forcing them with AS.

I've got it working by running the query three times and populating the results to an array three times, but it's practically grew three times in size code wise and just feels really inefficient now.

Bear in mind this is for a university project, but since I've already got a solution at hand and understand the basics of what is happening I thought it would be fine to post ahead.

Thought I'd add the actual JSON it is returning now:

```
[
   {
      "student_no":"testing"
   },
   {
      "group_id":"testio"
   },
   {
      "leader":"teeesstt"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible with an `UNION`, as [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) explains:

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned

What is possible is:

```
$query = "SELECT 'student_no' AS key, student_no AS value
        FROM student
        WHERE student_no='$studentno' AND password='$password'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'group_id',group_id
        FROM student_group
        WHERE student_no='$studentno'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'leader',leader
        FROM team
        WHERE leader='$studentno'";
```

You'll get the index in the first column and the value in the second one.

I don't think it's better than doing 3 queries though...

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I wanted to understand the code first. I see what you mean, your suggestion instead gives a static first column ID of student for all entries for the key index and gives "test" to the second column, (possibly due to the "AS test". 

I could rename these better and have them pass as key and value indicators.

Thank you very much tmuguet, mysql is a weakpoint of mine and php I am still adjusting to.

But as you mentioned, you feel it's no better than doing three queries? Could you explain the reasoning behind this? Currently I have "query, result, write output[]" x3

Comment: I edited my answer with the correct aliases (key, value). The problem with an `UNION`, is that if you have different data types (`char`, `int`, ...) for a column, it won't work well (I don't know how bad, though). And the problem with embedding the keys in your query is that it's more static, less re-usable; that may or may not be a big deal depending on your project.

Comment: I don't think it will have too much impact either way, it's currently a POC. Thanks again tmuguet, greatly appreciated. And apologies for the late reply, too many late nights!